# Rerender Events / Refresh Events from an external source [FC5.2.0]

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I get the events from a database with eventSources. This works well.
When I duplicate events in the database (outside the calendar) and would like to refresh with calendar.render() this does not work, because the existing events have not changed. It works by refreshing the browser.
With calendar.destroy() and then calendar.render() the calendar seems not to rerender.
Calling calendar.destroy() an calling calendar.render() afterwards should work, right?
This does not work in my environment

Comment: calendar.render() just redraws the calendar, it doesn't fetch new events from the server. If you have defined an events source as either a URL or a function then you can use the refetchEvents() command to make fullCalendar look for new events

Comment: Sometimes the solution is obvious. Thank you very much.